# Application Analytics report requests with more than 1 dependent call

Tags: azure-application-insights

I understand how to use `requests` and `dependencies` in a query.

How can I only list requests having more than a specific number of dependencies?

Comment: I suggest looking at [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/joinoperator) and [count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/count-aggfunction). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, if the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The comment is right, you should use join and count for your purpose. Note that the requests and dependencies are related by `operation_Id`.

Please use the code below which works for me (list requests that have more than 3 dependencies).

```
let myrequests = requests
    | where timestamp > ago(1h)
    | join (dependencies | where timestamp > ago(1h))
      on operation_Id
    | summarize mycount=count() by operation_Id
    | where mycount > 3;

    requests
    | where timestamp >ago(1h)
    | join myrequests
    on operation_Id
```

Result as below:

[image]